# Testing async with karma

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to set up some async tests using karma and jasmine.  I am clearly making a very stupid mistake but I need it pointing out to me.  After simplifying as much as possible I have the following:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "newtest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma": "^0.12.28",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.2"
  }
}
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'tests/**/*.js'
    ],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

tests/dummy.spec.js

```
describe("Testing async", function() {
  it('should fail this test', function(done) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      expect(1).toBe(2);
      done();
    }, 1000);
  });
  it('should not fail this test', function(done) {
    done();
  });
});
```

and I am getting the following:

```
npm test
> newtest@0.0.0 test /home/mark/Projects/newtest
> karma start karma.conf.js
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 39.0.2171 (Linux)]: Connected on socket T7j6LvNAwvS89wUdymCb with id 16891024
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Linux) Testing async should not fail this test FAILED
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at null.<anonymous> (/home/mark/Projects/newtest/tests/dummy.spec.js:12:5)
Chrome 39.0.2171 (Linux): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.007 secs / 0.005 secs)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

So the test that I think should fail is passing fine, and vice-versa.  Can someone point me to my error(s)?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/stips/using-jasmine-2.0s-new-done-function-to-test-asynchronous-processes.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first one fail because when the timeout is reach the test is allready finish, so both doesn't work.

It's has you'r not using jasmine 2.

The syntax seems good to me, what I can tell you is the difference with my configuration (wich is working) :

I have put karma-jasmine in dependencies with a ~ :

```
"dependencies": {
...
"karma-jasmine": "~0.2.0"
},
```

I'm using PhantomJS :

```
browsers:['PhantomJS'],
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I did try them both (despite the fact that I should already be on Jasmine 2 and browser shouldn't make a difference) but I am getting exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I am having the problem, but I have tried on another machine and it works as expected.

Comment: I don't know if it's posible but maybe you have multiple version of jasmine install ? (localy and globaly ?)